# Bottle on Python, how to make a custom response

Tags: python, bottle

Well, I am working with bottle right now. And I am now wondering how excatly I am able to build a custom response. I have a little script which operates some data, which I send and then, I want to send a response-code, if there was done some modification or not ... I was looking through the docs of bottle and didn't find anything ...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create custom responses, you need to use a `bottle.BaseResponse` object. The [documentation](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.BaseResponse) describes the class, and it seems quite easy to use. So, to achieve what you want, just create a `BaseResponse` object with the status code you wish (and any other data you'd need to include), and return it from your view.